# JavaFX equivalent of Swing's JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, spinner, javafx-2

I was trying to find a spinner component like [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) to use in my JavaFX application but there is no such component.

What JavaFX component do you recommend me to use in place of a spinner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update for Java 8**

JavaFX 8 has now an in-built [Spinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html) class as part of the core JavaFX library (as mentioned in [SWdV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376454/1155209) to this question).

**Old (pre-Java 8) Answer**

There is a spinner control in the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) library, you could use that implementation or possibly adapt it to your needs.

A spinner control is proposed for inclusion in a future JavaFX version.  The target version is currently unspecified, so perhaps it won't even be released with Java 8.  The [proposed spinner control](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-5747) has a [usability design document](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/ux/spinner/index.html).  The [open-jfx](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/) project may accept a quality implementation of the usability design for inclusion into the core JavaFX platform or the [JavaFX UI Control Sandbox](http://fxexperience.com/2012/10/announcing-the-javafx-ui-controls-sandbox/).

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX 8 has a [Spinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html) class. (but earlier versions haven't)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check and follow my initial approach to the spinner implementation problem, which you can find here: 
https://github.com/bluevoxel/Custom_Spinner_JavaFX8/wiki

And thats how it looks like:

[image]

Its functionality is constantly expanding, so I will be very grateful for your feedback.

**UPDATE 4/11/2014**

There is a new version available with expanded functionality including `double`s, additional customizable `ContextMenu` class for choosing the `incrementation value`, additional method for uploading custom functionality to `increase/decrease` buttons. Check the link below to know more:

https://gist.github.com/bluevoxel/c730a101ba812728a235

Also, there is a new outlook lack of external image files:

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/ux/spinner/index.html