# JavaFX Combobox with up/down arrows

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-2

With JavaFX, is there any possibility to having Combobox with up/down arrows? like follows,
[image: Combobox]

With this [article](http://www.jidesoft.com/jidefx/JideFX_Fields_Developer_Guide.pdf) page 11, under "Mouse and Keyboard Support" section, they have mentioned we can derive such a capability with "JideFX Decoration", but how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Spinner together with a ListSpinnerValueFactory for this purpose.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.ListSpinnerValueFactory.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. 
Can you please put some sample code? it will be really helpfully to me.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Comment: So sorry I am using JavaFX 2.2 with Java 7. 
I have get resolved the issue by following this blog:  http://myjavafx.blogspot.sg/2013/05/developing-numberspinner-control.html.
I have found smiler post on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771325/javafx-equivalent-of-swings-jspinner